# selenium and phantomjs being detected right after entering the website?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

Here's the website: http://wsjs.saic.gov.cn
The default language is Chinese you can set it to English anyway.
They have encrypted their js I use chrome to get some keywords which I believe are related to the function that blocks the bots.
My code is :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import requests
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
headers = { 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
}
for key, value in headers.iteritems():
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.{}'.format(key)] = value
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:47.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'

print 'yeah'
url = 'http://wsjs.saic.gov.cn/'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.save_screenshot('fk1.png')
```

I successfully get all these keywords in the js files using chrome debug.

```
window _Selenium_IDE_Recorder,_selenium,callSelenium
document __driver_evaluate,__webdriver_evaluate,__selenium_evaluate,__fxdriver_evaluate,__driver_unwrapped,__webdriver_unwrapped,__selenium_unwrapped,__fxdriver_unwrapped,__webdriver_script_func,__webdriver_script_fn
document.documentElement.getAttribute ["selenium", "webdriver", "driver"]
window callPhantom,_phantom
```

Now I need to know how can I get away with it. Do I need to recompile phantomjs to get my script to work?

Upate:
Sine nobody answered my question, I had to work on it on my own.And I figured out that callPhantom _Phantom are two apis exposed than can be called by the website so they know. And there's no page.onInitialized api to selenium so I had to use phantomjs without a webdriver and I managed to get to the page and start inputting some info on the webpage.

Then I realized there's another problem. They also check the mouse movement to detect if you're a bot.
Here are some keywords they check:

```
mousemove`mousedown`mouseup`mouseover`mouseout`keydown`keyCode
```

I don't know how since I barely know JS. How do I get past this detection.I also noticed there're some keywords like 'abort diSpatEvent'.

Comment: Why are you setting `webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent']` for each header item? I think you don't need this statement at all

Comment: Nice question and a great analysis !!!